# Semantic issue when I load GameCenter Leaderboard

Tags: iphone, game-center

I have a warning message when I load Game Center Leaderboards with:

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != nil) {
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
}
```

Warning massage appears in third line, and It says:

> warning: Semantic Issue: Assigning to
>   'id' from incompatible type
>   'ViewMenuController *'

I understand the message but I don't know how solve it.
The code works fine, but I would like remove the warning or find if there is a better way to load leaderboards.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**

I have done two modifications in ViewMenuController.h:

Add this import:

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
```

and modify this line adding :

```
@interface ViewMenuController : UIViewController <GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate> {
```

Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: Check if `self` does not require implementation of `GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is when you are setting the `leaderboardDelegate` to self, it is expecting a `id<GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>`, but your `ViewMenuController` does not define itself as conforming to the `GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

Make sure you set this in the interface of `ViewMenuController`.